# How to determine sender's mulicast group&port pair from the received multicast message

Tags: c++, multicast, aix

I have written a service (C++) that runs on the AIX machine and receives Multicast messages from a remote host (my service joins a predefined Multicast group&port pair).

Lately, I've been asked to handle the Multicast messages received from a different host (on a different Multicast group&port, on the same socket. Though I can insist on the same port.

The issue is, that the messages received from each host must be handled differently.

How do I distinguish between these messages? Is there a possibility to retrieve the sender's Multicast group&port pair from the socket/received messages?

Answer (score 0):

While you can identify the remote host's address (not multi-cast group!) with recvfrom(); it's generally not a good idea to perform different actions for different host with listening same port. It's against the rule of least surprise.

So the short answer is to differentiate remote host address.

If you want to differentiate multi-cast groups on the same port, you have to bind multiple sockets with the multi-cast group address.

The code looks like this:

```
addr.set(239,0,0,1,8888);
udp.socket();
udp.joinmcast(&addr);
udp.bind(&addr);
```